# MRT (MODIS Reprojection Tool) input error

Tags: remote-sensing, error, modis

This is my first time to use Modis Swath Tool to deal with images. I've downloaded 4 MOD44B granules (using the FTP script method), and am trying to use MRT to mosaic them. When I add the 2 files I get an error saying firstly One of the input files does not exist or the inputs are not the same data product type then Input file does not exist!. If I add files individually, I get an error saying Error in Module: ReadHrFile, Opening Input Header File.

I saw this error before in this website, but I still failed to fix it following the answer to this question by opening ModisTool.BAT rather than the ModisTool.JAR executable. Any one knows how to fix it? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Versions:

MRT: 4.1 (March 2011)
Windows: 7
Java: 7

Comment: Have you tried using [MRTWeb](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/get_data/mrtweb) instead of the downloadable tool? And what format are your MOD44B granules in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at "pyModis", a Free and Open Source Python library to work with MODIS data. It can bulk-download, mosaik and reproject:

http://www.pymodis.org

Comment: Nice link! I wish I knew about this earlier--it probably would have saved many headaches I had with MRT.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, dmahr. I still failed in using MRTWeb to mosaic those images, and now I will try the method givn by markusN.

Comment: Thank you very much, markusN. This is indeed a nice link!